# create dynamic update sql query

Tags: javascript, sql

My problem is I dont want to update columns when there is no value available to update them. I know how to do it in sql but want to do it java script.

I have some variables and each belongs to specific columns only where they needs to be stored or updated.

```
Variable Names    Column Names

context.one       First
context.two       Second
context.three     Third
```

Let say I have value only in context.one and others are empty or null.

I want to create dynamic update sql query.

For example:

```
Update TableName
Set "column name whose relevant variable is having value" = variable name
Where ID = 100
```

Other columns should not come under set columns because their respective variables are empty.

Any suggestion please !!
Thanks

Comment: `Java` or `Javascript` ?

Comment: javascript...!! if possible otherwise how its possible in java

Comment: Why dont you create a function with the data you need as parameters ?

Comment: Can you give any suggestions ? How ?

Comment: Yup check my answer

Comment: Doing this will levae you code open to SQL injection attacks, I wouldn't do this

Comment: By Javascript do you mean node.js?

Comment: I think only java is fine..because am not so much into java part. If I find any suggestion I can understand the code using google

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will generate the queries. Just send the parameters you need : `data` and `column`

```js
var context = {
  "one": "Data1",
  "two": "",
  "three": null
}

var columns = {
  "one": "First",
  "two": "Second",
  "three": "Third"
}

//Iterate each keys of context object
Object.keys(context).forEach(function(key) {
  generateUpdateQuery(context[key], columns[key]);
});

function generateUpdateQuery(variableName, column){
  if(variableName === null || variableName === "")
    return;
  var query = "UPDATE table_name SET " + column + "='" + variableName + "' WHERE ID = 100;"
  console.log(query);
}
```

Comment: but if we found two columns to be selected in set column then how we would remove comma from second set statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Modified Weedoze's function to answer your question as to how you would create a multi column update query.

```js
var context = {
  "one": "Data1",
  "two": "Data2",
  "three": null,
  "four": "Data4"
}

var columns = {
  "one": "First",
  "two": "Second",
  "three": "Third",
  "four": "Four"
}

var query = "UPDATE table_name SET ";
Object.keys(context).forEach(function(key) {
  if(!(context[key] === null || context[key] === ""))
    query += columns[key] + "='" + context[key] + "',";  
});

query += " WHERE ID = 100";

//replace last comma from query
var n = query.lastIndexOf(",");
query = query.slice(0, n) + query.slice(n).replace(",", "");

console.log(query);
```