# Javascript: object keys json map execute function

Tags: javascript, json, object

On the application im working on, I load a user's record into an object using the following method

```
var rcpObj = NLWS.nmsRecipient.load(ctx.vars.id);
//update record
rcpObj.firstName = 'Dave';
rcpObj.origin    = 'WebApp';
rcpObj.save();
```

However, the fields to update and values depend on what a user fills in the form on the front end, these key/value pairs are sent in the form of an object string which I am iterating to get the keys and values and construct the fields to update.

example of an object structure is `{"firstName":"David prospect","origin":"phone"}`

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(ctx.vars.formData);

  var dynamicFields = Object.keys(jsonData)
                .map(function(key) {
                return 'rcpObj.'+key+' = '+jsonData[key]; //returns fields to update.
```

dataObj structure is returned as object `rcpObj.firstName= David prospect,rcpObj.origin= phone`
how do I execute it as as the following statement now that I have dynamically set the `rcpObj.<fieldname>`

```
rcpObj.firstName= 'David prospect';
rcpObj.origin= 'phone';
```

**explanation**
The object keys will be used to construct the object method field to update as there could be 10 or there could be 2 (they are dynamic depending on whats filled in the form)

`for each key in object construct field to update`

`rcpObj.<key> = value`

This is the whole script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(ctx.vars.mergeData);
try {

    var rcpObj = NLWS.nmsRecipient.load(ctx.vars.id);
    var dataObj = Object.keys(jsonData)
        .map(function(key) {
            return 'rcpObj.' + key + ' = ' + "'" + jsonData[key] + "'"
        })
        .join(';');
    //logInfo(dataObj); //returns structure of fields to update i.e rcpObj.firstName = 'David Dynamic';rcpObj.emailPreferredName = 'David G.'
    logInfo(typeof dataObj);
    logInfo(dataObj);
    Function('return '+dataObj)();
    rcpObj.save();

} catch (err) {
    logInfo(err);
} finally {

}
```

I am getting rcpObj is not defined,

```
022-08-31 09:45:42 ReferenceError: rcpObj is not defined 
2022-08-31 09:45:42 rcpObj.firstName = 'David Dynamic' 
2022-08-31 09:45:42 string 
2022-08-31 09:45:42 Outside Loop Wed Aug 31 2022 09:45:42 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

**update, here is what I am trying to do, but the fields need to be dynamic, hence why I am tring to contruct the following statement dynamically.**

```
var rcpObj = NLWS.nmsRecipient.load(ctx.recipient.@id);

//to be dynamic: this section needs to be dynamic
rcpObj.leadScore = rcpObj.leadScore +5;
rcpObj.marketingConsentLastUpdated=new Date()
rcpObj.dataWaiverLastUpdated=new Date();
//end dynamic 
  
rcpObj.save();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but `rcpObj = { ...rcpObj, ...jsonData }`?

Comment: You have not dynamically set an object and your `map` does not return an object, it returns an array of strings. I think you are confusing key/value pairs (from forms) with objects (which seems to be what your API sends you). This needs some clarification on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The keys will be used to construct the `rcpObj.<keyhere> = <valuehere>`

Comment: I am parsing the object, I need to iterate through the keys and values to construct the update as explained in the first paragraph

Comment: Same context to how they are constructing the sql statement here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802118/create-dynamic-update-sql-query but mine isnt a sql statement.

Comment: I understand but is your output an object or a string? You keep using confusing variable names here like `rcpObj` and `dataObj` and then assigning a string to them. Are you trying to create a key/value list to use as a GET url to sort of post it? Are you trying to construct `rcpObj` as an object? Do you need it as a string? That's whats unclear to me here. Just provide what the input is, what the output of that input should be and what you tried.

Comment: It wont be used to post or get on url but rather, to construct the same structure as the first paragraph

Comment: Holy crickey this is overcomplicated. You use Function to create the object? Why even do this? You can merge objects with @Nick 's suggestion much more easily. Why even turn it into a string your need to eval instead of just assigning them as `rcpObj[key] = jsonObj[key]`? The `eval`/`Function` system is going to cause user code to be evaluated, very dangerous.

Comment: Could you give me some sample code I can test?

Comment: As @Nick suggested, use `rcpObj = { ...rcpObj, ...jsonData }` which will do two things: create a new Object (`{}`), then first fill it with your old object (`...rcpObject`), then override it with any keys in your jsonData (`...jsonData`), then it will assign this new object to the variable `rcpObj`.